# How to disable GraphQL Playground in Serverless production?

Tags: graphql, serverless-framework

Is there a way to disable the playground function in production?

In my serverless.yml

```
functions:
  graphql:
    # this is formatted as <FILENAME>.<HANDLER>
    handler: handler.graphqlHandler
    events:
    - http:
        path: api/v1
        method: post

  playground:
    handler: handler.playgroundHandler
    events:
    - http:
        path: playground
        method: get
```

In my handler.js

```
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-lambda";
import lambdaPlayground from "graphql-playground-middleware-lambda";

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => "Hello world!"
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

export const graphqlHandler = server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true
  }
});
export const playgroundHandler = lambdaPlayground({
  endpoint: "/api/v1"
});
```

Comment: [Apollo Server 2](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/graphql-playground.html#Enabling-GraphQL-Playground-in-production) comes with a build in playground that is "disabled in production" (as in `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`). Alternatively it allows you to specifically set a boolean value for the playground which could be hooked to an environment variable. So maybe updating could be worth it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set your NODE_ENV=production
or set `playgroundAlways:false`

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema, 
  introspection: false,
  playground: false,
});
```

In development, Apollo Server enables GraphQL Playground on the same URL as the GraphQL server itself (e.g. http://localhost:4000/graphql) and automatically serves the GUI to web browsers. When NODE_ENV is set to production, GraphQL Playground (as well as introspection) is disabled as a production best-practice.